# Write rows bottom in Google Sheet from Python

Tags: python, google-sheets, google-sheets-api, gspread

I am trying to write rows with python in one google sheet. I found function .insert_row() with that new rows are written in the top of my google sheet. How can I write it in the bottom? Any ideas?

That is how I am trying it now:

```
sheet.insert_rows(df_test.values.tolist())
```

Comment: What does the documentation for `sheet.insert_rows()` say? There's probably a parameter that indicates the row you want to insert at.

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand `Write rows bottom in Google Sheet`. Can I ask you about the detail of your goal?

Comment: @Tanaike it means I want to write new rows after last rows. For example I have already 10 rows in the sheet, I want to write new rows from the row 11. At the moment the new rows would write from row 1.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I have to apologize for my poor English skill. I would like to confirm my understanding of your goal. In your situation, the sheet has 1000 rows. But, the rows which are not empty are from 1st row to row 10. You want to put the values from the next empty row that it's the row 11. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: By guessing your situation from your replying and script, I proposed an answer. Could you please confirm it? If I misunderstood your situation, I apologize.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe your goal is as follows.

- In your situation, for example, the sheet has 1000 rows. The rows which are not empty are from 1st row to row 10.
- You want to put the values from the next empty row that it's row 11. This is the 1st empty row.
- From your script of `sheet.insert_rows(df_test.values.tolist())`, you want to achieve this using gspread for python.

In this case, how about the following modification? In this modification, `append_rows` method is used instead of `insert_rows`.

#### From:

```
sheet.insert_rows(df_test.values.tolist())
```

#### To:

```
sheet.append_rows(df_test.values.tolist(), value_input_option="USER_ENTERED")
```

#### Reference:

- [append_rows](https://docs.gspread.org/en/latest/api.html?highlight=append_rows#gspread.worksheet.Worksheet.append_rows)